# Uploading CSV file to dropbox.com format issue

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome-app, dropbox-api, export-to-csv

I am trying to create a chrome extension that uploads files straight to dropbox.com. Everything works fine apart of the csv format. The code below showcases how I create and format the file, then I automatically download it. When I open it it looks fine, the issue is when I upload the same file format to dropbox.com, when I open it afterwards it:

- doesn't recognize the '`/n`' (endlines)
- treats white spaces as '`%20`' and
- appends at the beginning of the file '`data:text/csv;charset=utf-8`'.

NOTE: Again if I download straight to my computer all the format is alright, the problem is only when I am uploading it to box.com and open it.

```
var csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,";
csvContent += localStorage["Table"];

var date = new Date();
// filename contains the unique user id + a timestamp of the current date with year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds
var filename=uniqueID +"  "+date.getYear()+ "-" +date.getMonth() +"-" +date.getDate() +": " +date.getHours() + "." +date.getMinutes() +": "+date.getSeconds()+".csv";

var encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
var link = document.createElement("a");
link.setAttribute("href", encodedUri);
link.setAttribute("download", filename);
link.click();
```

This is the code for uploading the file to dropbox

```
var uploadUrl = 'https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/files_put/dropbox/folder/'+filename;


var headers = {

    Authorization: 'Bearer '+localStorage.authorization_token
};

$.ajax({
    url: uploadUrl,
    headers: headers,
    type: 'PUT',
    // This prevents JQuery from trying to append the form as a querystring
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    data: link
}).complete(function ( data ) {
    // Log the JSON response to prove this worked
    console.log(data.responseText);
});
```

Comment: See [Data URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) and use `base64` encoding via `btoa()` or `encodeURIComponent` ONLY for `localStorage["Table"]` contents.

Comment: I don't see anything in the code that uploads the file to Dropbox. Can you share that code? Also, you mentioned box.com at one point, so I'm not 100% sure which product you're working with.

Comment: I am only using dropbox. I will add the code for uploading below

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, it looks like you're trying to pass `link` (an anchor tag?) as the data. I imagine you want to pass `localStorage["Table"]` instead, which I surmise is where the actual CSV is.

So try something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: uploadUrl,
    headers: headers,
    type: 'PUT',
    // This prevents JQuery from trying to append the form as a querystring
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    data: localStorage["Table"]
}).complete(function ( data ) {
    // Log the JSON response to prove this worked
    console.log(data.responseText);
});
```